# Secular alternative to "cardinal sin"

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a secular alternative to the term *cardinal sin* as used to describe a significant act that goes against established knowledge, beliefs, and practices. Any ideas?

Comment: People still use *cardinal sin* even if they are not religious fanatics.

Comment: _Cardinal_ only has religious overtones as a noun; as an adjective it also appears in _cardinal vowels, cardinal points,_ etc. As for _sin_, it gets used for nonliturgical things pretty often -- though the sexual overtones are undoubtedly religious in origin. Without an example of what you mean, it's hard to find the mot juste.

Comment: The term just seems out-of-place to me in technical documentation. I wish to indicate that "breaking compatibility is a cardinal sin".

Comment: @MichaelDudley Oh *that’s* what you mean! I always call that a “breach of contract” myself.

Comment: Most people at most times would consider the switch of domains fine - they wouldn't have a second thought about an inappropriate metaphor. However, if someone had just thrown a ripe tomato at one of the Pope's entourage...

Comment: There's the phrase "***Bozo No-No"*** but I'm sure that would be considered too localized: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bozo%20no-no :-)

Answer (score 2):

You might use *violation* or *breach* instead of *sin*. But outside of criminal law, where *felony* is distinguished from *misdemeanour*, we don't ordinarily rank violations, but qualify them ordinally: *serious breach*, *gross violation*. Instead, we rank the tenets or principles or practices which are violated; although you will encounter *fundamental violation* and similar phrases, these are elliptical for  *violation of the fundamental principle that ...* or *breach of the cardinal tenet, ...*.

Comment: "Fundamental violation" was going to be my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily avoid *[cardinal sin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins)* by instead referring to *capital vices* or *[mortal sin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_sin)*.  You might also refer to  *[heresy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heresy)* (“A controversial or unorthodox opinion held by a member of a group...”); for example, “Breaking compatibility is heresy/[heretical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heretical)”.

Regarding previously-mentioned *[taboo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/taboo#Noun)*, whose senses include “An inhibition or ban that results from social custom or emotional aversion” as a noun and  “Excluded or forbidden from use, approach or mention” as an adjective, and  *[faux pas](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faux_pas#Noun)* (“A blunder (especially used in social contexts); a misstep”),  you can suggest more severity via adjectives like unbreakable and unpardonable (*ie* unbreakable taboo, unpardonable faux pas).  Note, the synonyms  *[gaffe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gaffe#Noun)* (“A foolish and embarrassing error, especially one made in public”),  *[blunder](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blunder#Noun)* (“A clumsy or embarrassing mistake”), and *[misstep](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misstep#Noun)* might also work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *faux pas* or *taboo*, but neither of these suggest a high level of severity. *Verboten* might work, but it's an adjective rather than a noun.